# NextJS build with external types not working (types directory not found in server project)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tsconfig

When I try to build my NextJS project I get the error:

```js
../server/src/services/account/controllers/admin/manager/get.managers.c.ts:1:15
Type error: Module '"types"' has no exported member 'Controller'.

> 1 | import type { Controller } from "types";
    |               ^
  2 | import type { User, ManagerAccount } from "@prisma/client";
  3 | import { StatusCodes } from "http-status-codes";
  4 | import { prisma } from "config";
```

My folder structure is as follows:

```
root 
  - client
     ... (regular nextjs project, tsconfig below)
  - server
     - src
       - types
     ...
```

The `tsconfig` on the client is as follows:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@server/*": ["../server/src/*"],
      "@prisma/client": ["../server/node_modules/@prisma/client"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "../server/src/types"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Server `tsconfig`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },

  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    },
    "files": true,
    "esm": true
  },

  "include": ["src/**/*", "src/scripts/**/*", "types/*.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "src/types"]
}
```

In order to have end to end type safety I use the types defined on the server but whenever I try to build it fails with the error above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You haven't shown your `types` file yet.

Comment: `types` is a folder, I don't think its necessary, this problem isn't concerning whats in the folder because everything works as intended when building the server. I think the problem is the tsconfig on my client isn't registering the path aliases from the server so when it tries to resolve the `Controller` type it can't find it. I can send the contents of `types` if it's needed.

Comment: what typescript version do you use?

Comment: @CuongDaoVan for both I used 4.6.4

Comment: may be I doesn't support `import type`

Comment: Can you show us where you export `Controller` from?